# Facebook Login with Parse.com Fails

Tags: facebook, facebook-login, parse-platform

I'm getting a `POST https://api.parse.com/1/users 400 (Bad Request)` returned from the following Parse.Facebook.Utils.logIn request:

```
FB.login(function(response) {
    if(response.status == "connected") {
        // build authData object for Parse
        var id = response.authResponse.userID;
        var access_token = response.authResponse.accessToken;
        var expiration_date = new Date();
        expiration_date.setSeconds(expiration_date.getSeconds() + response.authResponse.expiresIn);
        expiration_date = expiration_date.toISOString();
        var authData = {
            "facebook" : {
                "id" : id,
                "access_token" : access_token,
                "expiration_date" : expiration_date
            }
        };

        // log in with Parse
        Parse.FacebookUtils.logIn(authData, {
            success: this._fbLoginSuccess,
            error: this._fbLoginError
        });
    }
}, this.FB_PERMISSIONS);
```

The `authData` object I create is based on [this format](https://parse.com/docs/rest#users-login) and [this API](https://parse.com/docs/js/symbols/Parse.FacebookUtils.html#.logIn).

How can I fix this? I've had no luck with using Parse.FacebookUtils.logIn with the standard permissions parameter (on mobile web and with PhoneGap), which is why I'm authenticating without it and using the `authData` parameter instead.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Is this using the JS SDK or are you rolling your own?

Comment: This is using the JS SDK. I'm required to log in a user through Parse, but the regular `Parse.FacebookUtil.logIn` doesn't work, so instead I log them in with the regular FB SDK and then use the authData to log them in through Parse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `authData` object should start from within the `facebook` key, like so:

```
var authData = {
        "id" : id,
        "access_token" : access_token,
        "expiration_date" : expiration_date
};
```